# Java Core Exam Theory

Tags: java, eclipse

For the following class what is the correct implementation of the Callable interface?

```
    class Process implements Callable<List<Set<String>>>{    }

A.  public Future< List<Set<String>>> call() throws Exception
B.  public void call(List<Set<String>> data) throws RuntimeException
C.  public List<Set<String>> call(String data) throws RuntimeException
D.  public List<Set<String>> call() throws Exception
```

I've implemented this in Eclipse and the answer is D. What I want to know is, how would I know whether or not the class would throw an Exception or a RuntimeException? Is there some way to differentiate? I know a Runtime exception is an unchecked exception and that an Exception is checked, but is there a hint somewhere in the question to tell me that it's the Exception class? If I didn't implement this in Eclipse there's no way I would have known that the call method doesn't accept a String parameter therefore it would either be C or D. How should I have known the answer was throws Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While implementing the method, you have to specify the exact same interface, which is

```
V call() throws Exception
```

like [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) sais. However, you can make the `throws` clause more restrictive, which means you can specify that you throw i.e. `RuntimeException` like here - which is a subclass of `Exception`. Therefore, the `throws` declaration here does not tell you the answer. These are the arguments and return type that do.

The return type here has to be `List<Set<String>>`, because it is specified as `V` parameter (as in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) again) in

```
class Process implements Callable<List<Set<String>>>{    }
```

Another thing is that `call()` method does not take any argument.

Taking those into consideration, only answer D is left here. It both returns an appropriate type and takes no arguments. Hope it helps you!

Comment: But without access to the documentation, I wouldn't have known that the call method throws exception. Is there any clues inside the question or is it just down to whether or not you have experience with the interface?

Comment: I think that it is a matter of knowing the interface. Without this you couldn't know what arguments call() takes and what it returns.
Obvoiusly, you could exclude A at the very beggining, because of the return type - by intuition, such type is not specified anywhere in the question, so it's most probable (but not sure unless knowing the interface) that it is incorrect.